# grub boots from another /boot partition, encrypted partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption, boot-repair

I installed both Ubuntu and Debian, and Debian doesn't show in grub. Apparently it doesn't recognize the boot partition. The encrypted partition of Debian (which is where the OS is installed) is located on `/dev/sda7` and `/boot` on `/dev/sda6`. I added the option manually, but when it boots I get several errors.

[image]

Comment: The non-encrypted install need LVM & encryption drivers. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup` And then mount encrypted drive before running `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I've tried that,it didn't work.

Comment: Are they all in same boot mode, or all UEFI or all BIOS? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://pastebin.com/A7Vt7cL2

Comment: You also need to unencrypt & mount the LVM partition for report to include everything.  I would suggest backing up your 40_custom & total reinstall of grub. The grub proxy files are from grub customizer and may be interfering.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xpuRGXJH here is the report with the encrypted partition mounted(note that I mounted only this partition not the /boot one) as for grub I couldn't figure out how to reinstall it and I don't think reinstalling it would help but If you insist could you provide me with a link that would help me?

Comment: Since you have new UEFI system but all installs are old BIOS/MBR configuration be sure to always boot in CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot mode. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and check the full reinstall of grub ( and maybe latest kernel even if same.) https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: It didn't work the problem is not the grub nor the kernel. I tried installing debian without encrypted volume and not seperate /boot partition and it worked but I want to install it as encrypted is there any way I can boot to it with grub-customizer?

Comment: Do not know nor  use grub customizer. But if you add drivers as in first post that normally works. If  you do not have /boot with encrypted partition you probably need grub drivers or the mod files loaded first, but do not now LVM installs. this may have some more info: Full-system encryption with manual control and dual-booting Paddy Landau
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357627

Comment: if by drivers you're referring to the cryptsetup and lvm2 I've installed both of them but it just wont recognise the encrypted volume.I belive the issue is that I don't use the right commands to boot from the /boot partition.Thanks for helping could you specify what you mean with drivers?

Comment: Yes lvm2 & cryptsetup. But if not using /boot you need grub drivers which are called mod files. Basic grub has some features/drivers built in. But then it has many mod files to add whatever else is needed. I do not know LVM, but  believe the link posted has lots more info. Thread discusses, and details are here now: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this script in grub-customizer and It worked.

set root='(hd0,7)'

linux /vmlinuz-4.18.0-kali2-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/sda6_crypt initrd=/boot

/initrd.img-4.18.0-kali2-amd64

initrd /initrd.img-4.18.0-kali2-amd64

boot